# Applying rainbow text to all text in class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've found a really nice rainbow text animation that I like:
https://github.com/xoxco/Rainbow-Text

I'm trying to apply the effects of this to all text within a class.
`<span class="rainbow">some text here...</span>`

The problem is that if I have two different pieces of text on a page:

```
<span class="rainbow">Text #1</span>
<span class="rainbow">Text #2</span>
```

The rainbow affect applies to both pieces of text but the text contents of each span changes to `Text #2`.

The text isn't static on the page so I can't use `id`.

Is there a way I can change the class (or id) of each rainbow text span to `rainbow-1`, `rainbow-2` etc and have the javascript code execute on each span independently? Maybe a loop that iterates over id's beginning with `rainbow-` and applies the effect to it independently?

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle so we can see the code run?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You suspected correctly. By using jQuery's `.each` over the `.rainbow` elements, the text displays properly.

Here is the working code

```
$('.rainbow').each(function() {
  $(this).rainbow({
    colors: [
      '#FF0000',
      '#f26522',
      '#fff200',
      '#00a651',
      '#28abe2',
      '#2e3192',
      '#6868ff'
    ],
    animate: true,
    animateInterval: 100,
    pad: false,
    pauseLength: 100
  });
});
```

Here's a GIF of it in action!

[image]

Comment: Ooh, yours has a GIF, you win!

Comment: This is the correct answer, but it seems sketchy that the plugin makes you do this.  One of the great things about jQuery is using a class selector and implied iteration over each object that that selector returns.

Comment: Agreed, the developer of the library probably just overlooked the issue if I had to guess.

Comment: It seems like a tiny plugin, we could probably whip together a pull request

Comment: BTW, I had to poke around a little more, here's a version with a phased/waterfall effect:
http://jsfiddle.net/ajVzR/685/

Comment: Well after fiddling with it and getting it to work, I went to go make a pull request, and saw that someone else had already done the same thing. https://github.com/xoxco/Rainbow-Text/pull/3 lol.

Answer (score 4):

Sure, looks like the plugin expects you only declare one element at once.

You can put it inside an each loop, have your callback use an `i` variable to represent the current index, and use `$(this)` to instantiate it for each item with the class.

The end result will include your `.rainbow-1`, `.rainbow-2`, etc. classes as well.

```
$('.rainbow').each(function(i) {
  $(this).addClass('rainbow-' + i).rainbow({
    colors: [
      '#FF0000',
      '#f26522',
      '#fff200',
      '#00a651',
      '#28abe2',
      '#2e3192',
      '#6868ff'
    ],
    animate: true,
    animateInterval: 100,
    pad: false,
    pauseLength: 100
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ajVzR/683/

Answer (score 2):

you can use jQuery "each" for solving your problem, like bellow

```
<div class="foo">123456789</div>
<div class="foo">123456789</div>
<div class="foo">123456789</div>
<div class="foo">123456789</div>


    $(".foo").each(function(){
        $(this).rainbow({animate:true,animateInterval:10,colors:['#FF0000','#f26522','#fff200','#00a651','#28abe2','#2e3192','#6868ff']});
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can work around this like this:

```
$('.rainbow').each(function() {
$(this).rainbow({
    colors: [
        '#FF0000',
        '#f26522',
        '#fff200',
        '#00a651',
        '#28abe2',
        '#2e3192',
        '#6868ff'
    ],
    animate: true,
    animateInterval: 100,
    pad: false,
    pauseLength: 100
});
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ajVzR/684/)